# Single Sign On: SimpleSAMLPhp Service Provider Implementatio

Tags: single-sign-on, simplesamlphp

I am implementing a SSO using SimpleSAMLPhp Service Provider.

I provided my metadata to remote Shibboleth Identity Provider and was provided a test account.

When a user visits a specific page on my SP, they get redirected to the IdP, login, and are redirected back to my web site with a bunch of IdP provided attributes. This part works.

This part I am struggling with.

If the user authenticates with the same IdP through a different Service Provider and then visits my page, how do I know they are already authenticated? Currently I am being asked to login again.

Is there a configuration value somewhere that lets me do this? Or am I using the wrong method? This is what I am doing.

```
$as = new SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple({REMOTE_AUTHSOURCE});
$as->requireAuth(); // this redirects to remote IdP login
$attributes = $as->getAttributes();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate authentication sessions to consider. One session is in you app and the other is at the IdP. The `requireAuth` method can tell if the user already has an authenticated session in your application, and will return immediately in that case. 
There is no way for you to tell if a browser has a session at the IdP. You just call `requireAuth` whichs send the user there and if the IdP decides the user's session is still valid it will respond without prompting for login.

Are you saying that the user has a valid session at the IdP and they are being re-prompted to authenticate when you send the user there? That could be due to IdP policy, or if your app was sending something like 'forceAuth' in its AuthnRequest.